# Gnuplot pm3d palette colors not mapping to the values specified?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a solar spectrum.  I am having difficulty with Gnuplot mapping the colors that I specify to the correct values.  Here is my script.

```
set view map
set pm3d 
set palette defined (380 "purple", 475 "blue", 510 "green", 570 "yellow", 590 "orange", 650 "red", 675 "dark-red", 700 "black")
splot [400:800][0:1] x
```

[image]

As you can see at x=510, there plot is not green. Likewise it is not yellow at 570 as I specified.  How do I fix this so the colors on the plot match what I specified?

Answer (score 0):

I need to specify `cbrange` to match the plot ranges, e.g.

```
set view map
set pm3d 
set palette defined (400 "purple", 475 "blue", 510 "green", 570 "yellow", 590 "orange", 650 "red", 675 "dark-red", 700 "black")
splot [400:700][0:1] x
set cbrange [400:700]
```

so that the colors are scaled correctly.